# TFS 2018 - Build and Release - Library - Variable groups

Tags: tfs

I have read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/variable-groups but didn't find an answer..

Is it possible to use variables as values in another variable definiton?
Example:

- MyCopyToFolder = C:\TFS_deploy_target\
- MyConfigReplacements = $(MyCopyToFolder)ReplacementFolder\MyAppReplacements.ps1

I didn't find any word about that (im)possibility..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's supported since TFS 2015 update4.

I just checked that, everything works as expected with the variables expanded on TFS 2018. Reference below screenshot.

Refer to the similar thread : [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 release configuration variables not setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595115/visual-studio-team-foundation-server-2015-release-configuration-variables-not-se/46600015#46600015)

[image]